# What is the user Agent string of IE11 on windows 10

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Could you please provide the user Agent string of IE11 on windows 10.
I have verified all the sites but did not succeed.

Answer (score 25):

Standard user agent string: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`

In compatibility view: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/8.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)`

This is in build 10240 (launch day build.) I'm not sure why the Trident version got bumped up to 8 in compatibility view but not outside of it.

Comment: My Surface Pro's Windows 10 IE 11 agent string is: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko" .  Basically, the same except for the addition of the "Touch; " component.

Comment: double plus good for pointing out the compatibility view string is different

Answer (score 4):

The complete User-Agent of IE11 in windows 10 is

`"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko

source:
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Internet+Explorer